# Is there a limit on number of characters displayed in a status bar using SB_SETTEXT?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to display a long string in a status bar using MFC code like so:

```
// i've set only one pane in the status bar using CStatusBar::SetIndicators()

pFrameWnd->m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneText( 0, szText, TRUE );
```

But the string displayed in the status bar gets truncated to 127 chars.

Since the MFC class member [CStatusBar::SetPaneText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xz1t794.aspx) internally uses the message [SB_SETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760758.aspx), I want to know if there is any limit on the number characters we can display in a status bar using SB_SETTEXT?

I googled and found some discussion forums stating that there is indeed a limit but not a single one of them had any reference to MSDN documentation stating the same.

So, could anyone please provide an MSDN link to support their answer if there exists a limit on the number of characters?

Also, if indeed there's a limit, is there a way I can get around this and display more number of characters in a single pane in a status bar?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no documented limit on the length of the string. Have you tried sending a [WM_SETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644.aspx) message (as explained under [Status Bar Text Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760728.aspx#Status_Bar_Text_Oper)), and does the behavior change? Just to make sure this is not an issue with the status bar size, try setting the text to `L"Left\tCenter\tRight"`. Doing this will help you see the geometry of the status bar.

Comment: It's not a documented limit, but the `DrawStatusText` function seems to use a static buffer of size 128 internally, and this function is used by default when drawing each status bar part's text. So you could probably get around it using owner draw.

Comment: I've tried using CWnd::SetWindowText() (which in turn sends a WM_SETTEXT msg) but it didn't work.
The status bar size is OK as displaying "Left\tCenter\tRight" displays the strings left, centre and right in their respective positions on the status bar.
This link points to documentation for limit in number of chars:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1082b08e-6efa-46c8-9382-36e51247e1ba/status-bar-text-length-limit-?forum=vclanguage

Comment: I've tried using CWnd::SetWindowText() (which in turn sends a WM_SETTEXT msg) but no use.

Displaying "Left\tCenter\tRight" displays the strings left, centre and right in their respective positions on the status bar.
This link points to documentation for limit in number of chars:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1082b08e-6efa-46c8-9382-36e51247e1ba/status-bar-text-length-limit-?forum=vclanguage

But the link pointed to by the above link does not exist any more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/commctls/status/messages/sb_settext.asp

Comment: @JonathanPotter is there an internet link to that 128 limit?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I was able to get around the 127 char limitation using owner draw.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess: the issue is that these controls are internally limited to `32K` characters because internally they are limited to `64K` bytes. This is a few cases where the Win3.1 legacy (or Win95) shows up. Back then of Windows supported real mode which draw memory from something called the local heap. I can't find info for your actual control but here is [another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997530.aspx) one.

The notice that `SB_SETPARTS` limits the number of parts of a status bar to 255, so simple math would indicate that `127 = 32K/256` is a plausible limit per part. One could imagine they could handle a more dynamic allocation deal, but one could also imagine all sort of corner cases that could cause.

My guess is that there is no way do draw more using this control. I suggest you roll your own, possibly sub-classing 'static' one.

Ok, there is one other thing you can try for kicks. Try on an ANSI program, you might be able to do 255 ANSI chars per pane.

Comment: Thanks for yur reply AlienRancher.
I guess you're correct - it'a an undocumented thing although the limit is there.
Trying ANSI didn't help.
Finally, as suggested by Jonathan Potter, I tried owner draw trapping WM_DRAWITEM for the staus bar and was able to get around the 127 char limitation.

Comment: Doesn't sound convincing to me. It's not the internal storage that necessitates truncation (which your calculation implies). It's the **rendering** that truncates the pane text. You can call `SetPaneText` followed by `GetPaneText` and won't see any truncation, regardless of string length.